# Create ini file in current directory in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

The problem is I don't want to write any details into the ini file. I just want to create an ini file in the current directory or in another e.g. in the debug folder where the main .exe is.

```
//CIniWriter iniWriter("Logger.ini");
void CIniWriter::Init(char* szFileName)
{

    memset(m_szFileName, 0x00, 255);
    memcpy(m_szFileName, szFileName, strlen(szFileName));
}
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You just want an empty file?

Comment: yes. in current directory.

Comment: can't you just do `fopen("file.ini","w")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `GetCurrentDirectory` to get the path of your application then
`CreateFile` to create the actual file.

```
TCHAR currentDir[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR iniFile[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory( MAX_PATH, currentDir );

_stprintf(iniFile,_T("%s\\iniFile.txt"),currentDir);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( iniFile,GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,
NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```